# How scalable are Emacs Client-Server-Applications?

Tags: web-applications, emacs, client-server, scalability, elisp

Emacs is officially named a 'text editor' but used by many as an operation system. More precisely, Emacs can be described as an Lisp-interpreter and an environment for developing interactive applications. It has a client-server architecture and a sheer overwhelming amount of well documented functionality. As a Lisp-interpreter, it is extremely configurable too.

However, besides all this merits, I never heard about commercial (or lets say 'high load') client-server applications based on Emacs. It seems to be used mainly by highly skilled individuals with IT/math background. Why is that so? Did nobody ever had the idea to use Emacs (and Elisp) for his serious client-server application, or is Emacs simply not suited for this kind of mission? Is it not scalable enough, or is the computational model unsuited for team development in an industrial setting?

What are the limits for using Emacs as a plattform for large-scale client-server applications? Would it be possible to use the Emacs server for a web-application (with web-browsers as clients)?

Comment: Which editor do you consider to use to write your application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, it is possible (obvious [Turing complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness) link).

However, Emacs isn't multi-threaded, and I doubt anyone writes a non-threaded web service...

Comment: ah - that might be the short answer to a long question.

Answer (score 1):

Scalability is not a design goal of Emacs, as it is unnecessary for a text editor or any of the other applications that sit on Emacs, which usually focus on the client, not the server, as that is where a powerful editing environment is more useful.

Comment: My question was somehow related to my investigation of open-source ERP-Software. There is a lot of marketing going on in that area, but one can discover big gaps between the marketing statements and the actual software systems. Using Emacs, I figured out that almost anything the ERP systems offer I can find in Emacs too, often with much more functionality and less bugs. And many programmers, freelancers, scientists use Emacs just like an ERP - for a very small (1 person) enterprise. Therefore I asked myself why Emacs isn't used as a development platform.

Comment: Reading you comment, it seems that one idea I had before might be reasonable: use the combination of Emacs (as a very rich client) and Git (as a Server/DB for textfiles) to achieve something similar to a distributed client-server architecture, so an enterprise can share the configuration and textfiles on the server, but each user has his/her own single-threaded Emacs installation on the desktop.